# Verilog equivalent of "wait until ... for ..."?

Tags: vhdl, verilog

In a Verilog testbench, I'm trying to code the following behavior:

- Wait until an event occurs (rising / falling edge) for a maximum time, i.e. an equivalent of the VHDL instruction:

  ```
  wait until <event> for <duration>;
  ```

which has the following behavior (reminder):

- either the event occurs;
- or the duration expires.

Unless I'm mistaken, I did not find any direct equivalent of this function in Verilog... So I tried the following code:

```
reg watchdog;
// ...

// Set a signal 'watchdog' in background which will be triggered in 10 us.
fork
  watchdog <= #10_000 1'b1;
join

// Wait until SIGNAL is set to '1' *OR* watchdog event occurs.
@(posedge SIGNAL or posedge watchdog);

// Reset the watchdog
watchdog <= 1'b0;
```

This code does the work but the last instruction does not cancel or supercede the `fork` instruction. So, in a second call to this code (with for example `watchdog <= #50_000 1'b1;`), the first `watchdog` may be triggered (too soon unfortunately).

Any better idea? (either an equivalent or a way to cancel the first planned `fork`?)

P-S : to do it in SystemVerilog is not an option... ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do this in Verilog you need to use `disable`.  I would suggest getting rid of the `watchdog` signal entirely and just using two branches of a `fork`.

Below is a working example.  Note that each branch of the fork calls `disable f` if that branch succeeds.  Disabling the fork will terminate the branch which did not succeed.

```
module top;

reg signal;

task test();
   fork : f
      begin
         // Timeout check
         #10
         $display("%t : timeout", $time);
         disable f;
      end
      begin
         // Wait on signal
         @(posedge signal);
         $display("%t : posedge signal", $time);
         disable f;
      end
   join
endtask

initial begin
   // test signal before timeout
   fork
      test;
      begin
         signal = 0;
         #5;
         signal = 1;
         #5;
         signal = 0;
         #10;
      end
   join
   // test signal after timeout
   fork
      test;
      begin
         signal = 0;
         #15;
         signal = 1;
         #5;
      end
   join
end
```

Comment: Great! This do exactly the work. Still young padawan in Verilog, I had not yet fully understand the behavior of `fork ... join`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your `fork join` only has one process, so you are not doing anything in parallel.

This should do what you want:

```
fork : wait_or_timeout
  begin
    #10_000; //#10ms
    disable wait_or_timeout;
  end
  begin
    @(posedge SIGNAL);
    disable wait_or_timeout;
  end
join
```